# How to know what expression should be checked on the normal distribution map?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have gone through a process and arrived at, say, $P({X-1470\over 35}\ge {70\over 35}=2)$. Answers tell it equals $1-\Phi(2)$. Now, I know it has something to do with $\Phi(2)$, but in what way? I know it depends on where this $2$ takes place but don't know how accurately. If I were to compute $P({X-1470\over 35}\le {70\over 35}=2)$? What would the expression be there? I could really use any fundamental or even a succinct elucidation.

Comment: How is X distributed? As i understand this is  not a question about central-limit theorems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the usual notation $\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the so called [standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with expectation $0$ and variance $1$. By definition, if $Y$ has the said distribution then

$$P(Y<x)=\Phi(x).$$

If $X$ is normally distributed with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ then the distribution of

$$Y=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}.$$

is standard normal.

In your case

$$P\left({X-1470\over 35}\ge 2\right)=1-P\left(\frac{X-1470}{35}<2\right)=\Phi (2).$$

Because $P({X-1470\over 35}=2)=0$
$$P\left({X-1470\over 35}\le 2\right)=P\left({X-1470\over 35}< 2\right)=\Phi (2).$$